# Check if customer has already apply for Order return

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I am using OpenCart 2.0.0.1.

On front side if you know then there is page called "Previous Order" in account section. From where we can request for a order return.

Somehow I want to check if customer has already requested for order return because if customer has already request for a return then I don't want to display the Order return button. So that customer cannot request for the return for the same order.

What can I try next?

Comment: To accomplish this would only require a few queries and conditional statements but stackoverflow is not a place where people write code for you.  If you've already made an attempt but got stuck somewhere, please post a bit of your code and tell us about the specific problem you are having.

Comment: i have already did it with the query after i posted this question. All i wanted to know is if there are some feature available from admin side or not.
anyways Thanks @billynoah

Comment: in that case your question is off topic as it has nothing to do with programming as defined within the scope of stackoverflow.

Comment: @billynoah as i just i have alredy told you , i just wanted to know if an feature is available from admin side or not.  and thing is i found that solution with the query after i put this question on stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes I understand, there's nothing wrong with asking that but it would be off topic for this site.  Try opencart.com forums.